# Split iterations MPI

Tags: c++, mpi, openmp

There is an array of vectors of 8 elements (number of cores), in the loop, each vector is passed to the function. It is necessary to make on MPI so that the loop is executed in parallel and as soon as one process finds a value - terminate the work of the rest of the processes. I did it on the OMP, but unfortunately I do not understand the MPI.

```
    double t1 = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel
    {
#pragma omp for nowait
        for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
            vector<double> result = GradDown(x[c], 0.000000000001);
        }
        double t2 = omp_get_wtime();
        cout << "time: " << t2 - t1 << "\n"  << endl;
```

Comment: The question is nice, but lacks formatting and just a little more full code example. Incompleteness like that may stop reader from diving futher into details

Answer (score 0):

Your OpenMP example doesn’t terminate the other threads’ work when one thread completes either. The other threads continue running in the background.

As for how to accomplish this (in OMP or MPI), you need a shared flag to indicate completion which threads regularly check to see if they need to exit. The only good way to externally terminate a thread is to rely on its cooperation.

Comment: Yes you are right, this will not terminate the rest of the threads, but I will have the execution time of the first thread. My question is, rather, how to divide the iterations for each process on the MPI.

Comment: This will print the time for *every* thread, so your OpenMP code is wrong. Maybe you can solve this with `omp cancel`. In MPI it will be much harder to stop after one process has found the solution.